# How validate array input angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i repeated array of input by ng-repeat and want to validate by angular.
my input form is such as this. How validate array of inputs.

thanks.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
     <input name = "apartment.home[$index].name" ng-model='item.name' required>
     <span ng-show="apartment.home[$index].name.$error.required">
                                           name is required.</span>
     <input name = "apartment.home[$index].phone" ng-model='item.phone'>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the js?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for the usage. Here is the list:

```
<input
  ng-model="string"
  [name="string"]
  [required="string"]
  [ng-required="boolean"]
  [ng-minlength="number"]
  [ng-maxlength="number"]
  [ng-pattern="string"]
  [ng-change="string"]
  [ng-trim="boolean"]>
...
</input>
```

And here is an example:

```
<script>
   angular.module('inputExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.user = {name: 'guest', last: 'visitor'};
     }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label>
       User name:
       <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required>
    </label>
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">
       Required!</span>
    </div>
    <label>
       Last name:
       <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.last"
       ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10">
    </label>
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.lastName.$error.minlength">
        Too short!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.lastName.$error.maxlength">
        Too long!</span>
    </div>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>user = {{user}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.userName.$valid = {{myForm.userName.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.userName.$error = {{myForm.userName.$error}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.lastName.$valid = {{myForm.lastName.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.lastName.$error = {{myForm.lastName.$error}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.minlength = {{!!myForm.$error.minlength}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.maxlength = {{!!myForm.$error.maxlength}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```

and a .js example:

```
var user = element(by.exactBinding('user'));
var userNameValid = element(by.binding('myForm.userName.$valid'));
var lastNameValid = element(by.binding('myForm.lastName.$valid'));
var lastNameError = element(by.binding('myForm.lastName.$error'));
var formValid = element(by.binding('myForm.$valid'));
var userNameInput = element(by.model('user.name'));
var userLastInput = element(by.model('user.last'));

it('should initialize to model', function() {
  expect(user.getText()).toContain('{"name":"guest","last":"visitor"}');
  expect(userNameValid.getText()).toContain('true');
  expect(formValid.getText()).toContain('true');
});

it('should be invalid if empty when required', function() {
  userNameInput.clear();
  userNameInput.sendKeys('');

  expect(user.getText()).toContain('{"last":"visitor"}');
  expect(userNameValid.getText()).toContain('false');
  expect(formValid.getText()).toContain('false');
});

it('should be valid if empty when min length is set', function() {
  userLastInput.clear();
  userLastInput.sendKeys('');

  expect(user.getText()).toContain('{"name":"guest","last":""}');
  expect(lastNameValid.getText()).toContain('true');
  expect(formValid.getText()).toContain('true');
});

it('should be invalid if less than required min length', function() {
  userLastInput.clear();
  userLastInput.sendKeys('xx');

  expect(user.getText()).toContain('{"name":"guest"}');
  expect(lastNameValid.getText()).toContain('false');
  expect(lastNameError.getText()).toContain('minlength');
  expect(formValid.getText()).toContain('false');
});

it('should be invalid if longer than max length', function() {
  userLastInput.clear();
  userLastInput.sendKeys('some ridiculously long name');

  expect(user.getText()).toContain('{"name":"guest"}');
  expect(lastNameValid.getText()).toContain('false');
  expect(lastNameError.getText()).toContain('maxlength');
  expect(formValid.getText()).toContain('false');
});
```

All taken from angularjs.org documentation.

Comment: That's right, but you can use it as a template for your implementations.